# Вебсервер Apache+PHP под Win - как обновить OpenSSL?

Tags: apache, php

Имеется вебсервер под windows (для разработки) на Apache + PHP.
Необходимо обновить версию OpenSSL до 1.0 или выше.
В phpinfo было:
SSL Version     OpenSSL/0.9.8t

OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 0.9.8t 18 Jan 2012
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013

Установил OpenSSL - версия осталась прежней.
Скопировал файлы libeay32.dll и ssleay32.dll в папку Apache и теперь отображается:

SSL Version     OpenSSL/1.0.1e

OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013

OpenSSL обновился или нет? Что за OpenSSL Header Version?

Answer (score 2):

OpenSSL Header Version это как раз то, что используется. Новая версия OpenSSL у вас видимо установилась в другую папку. В то время как php собран со старой версией. Вам нужно пересобрать apache и php с новой версией openssl.

[Вот здесь хорошо объясняется в чем отличие header от library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924485/whats-the-difference-between-a-header-file-and-a-library)